# React/Web3Modal Doesn't Work on Mobile Browsers

Tags: react, bsc

This is my first question that I haven't seen asked before.  I am creating a DApp that allows a user to connect via Metamask or WalletConnect using the Web3Modal package in React.  Everything works great on all desktop browsers.  However, when trying to use the DApp on any mobile browsers, the DApp functions are unusable (buttons are greyed out but wallet address is shown as connected).  Does anyone have any advice or have encountered this issue before.

Thank you,
DappWeb3